# Can't save line by line my output into my csv

Tags: python, csv

I don't know why but my code saves my output into a csv file not line by line but character in each cell.

```
import csv

with open(r'/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/crosscheckmmm/Sheet 2-Table 1.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().endswith('"'):
            line = line.strip().strip(';')
            print(line)

import collections
counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
for row in line:
    counter[row[0]] += 1
writer = csv.writer(open("/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/crosscheckmmm/Sheet 2-Table 3.csv", 'w'))
for row in line:
    if counter[row[-1]]:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This is my data. The one that I see in my PyCharm output.

```
► Принять в работу | 20.09.2019 |  | "
► арихив  | 23.03.2019 |  | "
► Архив. | 10.09.2019 |  | "
► ПОЗВОНИТЬ после 12.00 | 03.07.2019 |  | "
► Архив,лечение дома | 02.03.2019 |  | "
► Новое событие | 31.05.2019 |  | "
► Нуралдин, как обстоит ситуация с клиентом? Что сейчас происходит? | 17.09.2019 |  | "
► архив | 06.04.2019 |  | "
```

but my code saves it like that

```
►

П
р
и
н
я
т
ь

в

р
а
б
о
т
у

|

1
7
.
0
9
.
2
0
1
9

|


|

""""
```

I don't even know why it does it like that. What could be a solution for that.

Comment: whats the expected outcome of that code  and what purpose has this counter thing?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I need to store the output as it is line by line in each row 
first row ► Принять в работу | 20.09.2019 |  | "
second row ► арихив  | 23.03.2019 |  | "

and so it is

Comment: [edit] your question and supply a "what the output should look like" for the file that you manipulate please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your last for loop,

```py
for row in line:
    if counter[row[-1]]:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

You iterate over the last string assigned to the `line` variable. What you should do instead is to save your modified lines in an array and iterate over that:

```py
lines = [] # create array
with open(r'/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/crosscheckmmm/Sheet 2-Table 1.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip().endswith('"'):
            line = line.strip().strip(';')
            lines.append(line)  # append stripped line to array
            print(line)

import collections
counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
for row in lines:  # iterate over lines array
    counter[row[0]] += 1
writer = csv.writer(open("/Users/gfidarov/Desktop/crosscheckmmm/Sheet 2-Table 3.csv", 'w'))
for row in lines:  # iterate over lines array
    if counter[row[-1]]:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Nothing now I am getting empty file 0bytes

Comment: that's because your `if` condition is probably never met, I just wanted to show you why your program writes a bunch of characters to each row.